# Form_for vs. form_with in Rails 5 with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a namespaced resource in my Rails 5 app and want the correct form for it.

My scaffold for Platform in Rails 5 gave me:

```
<%= form_with(model: platform, local: true ) do |form| %>
```

In Rails 4 I would include my namespace ('customer') like:

```
<%= form_for [:customer, @platform] do |f| %>
```

So what is the equivalent in Rails 5?

Answer (score 16):

In your form you would do something like this.

```
<%= form_for [@customer, @platform] do |form| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

In `new.html.erb` or equivilent `new` method:

```
<%= render 'form', customer: @customer %>
```

In your new controller method (depending on your relationships)

```
def new
  @customer = @platform.customers.build
end
```

Using `form_with`

```
<%= form_with(model: [:customer, @platform]) do |form| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with

Comment: Is there an option in Rails 5 to achieve this with form_with instead of form_for?

Comment: Yes, the end of the answer shows the form_with version - you include the namespacing in what you pass to the `model`, like so: `model: [:customer, @platform]`

Comment: correct me if im wrong but most of your examples are showing nested resources, not namespaced resources.